# How to properly implement an Array that stores the JavaFX Text elements?

Tags: javafx, arraylist, text, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm currently working on a project in JavaFX with SceneBuilder.
So all the elements you see here haven been supplied by a FXML file linked to the Controller.

The project has a round based GameLoop, simplified here in a while Loop (The "onClick" function)
During the different rounds, I'd like to add different playerscores to a scoreboard on the screen.

The scoreboard has a set amount of text elements, so I thought it would be a wise idea to store them in an Array (now ArrayList) in order for easier access and to update them accordingly e.g. -> text1 stores score, then text2 stores score and displays it.

When testing I noticed that this solution does not work. Instead of storing the supplied texts, the ArrayList "Throw" always gives out null when printing it to the console

```
public class Controller {

    public Button Game501;
    private AlertBox Spieleranzahl = new AlertBox();
    private BorderPane Menübar;

    public Text text1;
    public Text text2;

    int i = 0;

    ArrayList<Text> Throw = new ArrayList<Text>() {{
        add(text1); add(text2);                             // text elements to cycle through and update 
                                                               successively (only 2 here)
    }};

    ArrayList<Integer> score = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(50); add(100);                                   //example of added scores
    }};

    public void onClick() {

        if (i==0) {


            Throw.get(i).setText(String.valueOf(score.get(i)));        // Throw.get(i) gives 
                                                                           nullException
            i++;

        }   else if (i==1 ) {


            Throw.get(i).setText(String.valueOf(score.get(i))); // using text2.settext... would work, but 
                                                                   then I cant cycle through my text                                                                    
                                                                   elements
            i=0;
        }

    }
}
```

You can imagine clicking the button alternating between the two if statements e.g. player turns, it is simplifed here, but you get the idea.

Is there a way to circumvent to nullExcpetion or do I need to find an entirely different method of cycling through different text elements, if so how could I achieve this?

Comment: a) no double bracet initialisation. You save a few chars, but every time you do this the result is an additional .class file. Instead use a constructor or an initializer block for the initialisation: `List<Integer> score = new ArrayList<>(2); { score.add(50); score.add(100); }` b) The lifecycle of a controller instance (usually) starts as follows: 1. `FXMLLoader` creates an instance; This initializes all variables 2. `FXMLLoader` values injects to fields 3. `initialize()` is called, if present. In your case the field values are retrieved in step 1, i.e. at the time they still contain `null`.

Comment: Long story short: add `@FXML private void initialize()` and use that method to create+fill the list containing the nodes.

Comment: java naming conventions please